# Dynamic stored procedure and Entity framework Issue

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have create a dynamic stored procedure in MS Sql server. It is working fine. But when I am using it with the entity framework it shows no results.

Sample of my stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL='My Dynamic query here'
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

Only stored procedures with sp_executesql are not working. Any Idea?

Comment: Have you examined the query that gets generated via SQL Profiler?

Comment: When I run query in MSSQL Server it is showing me correct results.